# No BIOS, no video after Ubuntu updates

Tags: video, updates, bios

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 on a Dell Precision T3500 Desktop machine.  Last week, when I ran the regular updates, upon restart my video disappeared.  I could not even see the Dell startup screen or enter the BIOS.

When I swapped out the video card (for an older one I had around), the system worked again.  So Dell sent me a replacement video card.  I put that in and everything appeared to be working again.

Then, I ran updates again, and the same thing happened.  Replacement video card appears to be broken.  No startup messages, no BIOS, no video at all.

Does anyone know how Ubuntu updates might be ruining the video cards?

The card that keeps "breaking" is an FirePro MV2260.

Answer (score 2):

That really doesn't make any sense. An OS update shouldn't completely "kill" hardware. This sounds more like a hardware issue. If I am mislead and someone knows the answer, I would be interested in hearing it.

Comment: +1 - I would say the same. I was going to vote up but my votes are reloading :D

Comment: +1 It's more likely that your computer is dirty. Suddenly, my pc refused to start, I could not even see a BIOS screen. After powering it off and clearing the dust, it worked again.

Comment: Arch Linux somehow seemed to kill my ethernet port every time I installed it. Broke it for Arch, Ubuntu, and Win7, all on the same HDD. I'm somewhat concerned that it might be possible :/

Comment: That sounds like proprietary drivers that need to be compiled upon each kernel update. This happens when you compile drivers that are not included in the linux kernel. This would not "ruin" the card but the system may not work after an update if no new driver is available.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar experience some time ago, however not with an ATI card, but nVidia. I was running Ubuntu 32 bit and with dual screens on an nVidia 7900 GT connected via DVI. I switched to AMD64 (clean install) and all was fine until I installed the proprietary driver.

As soon as I did that the screens were blank when the system was on, right from power on. There was no output from the BIOS, nothing whatsoever. I removed the DVI cables and switched back to VGA (with a pair of DVI-VGA adapters plugged into the card). It worked. If I switched back to DVI again it would fail.

The cables are fine, and have been used since (this issue was a few years ago) and the card is fine, still in use. I reported the issue to nVidia who basically told me the card was broken - it isn't, it's still in use today, 64-bit, analog VGA cables.