# Problem in installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: dual-boot

I am novice to the Linux. I used Ubuntu on my laptop.
Recently in my Lab I tried to use Ubuntu as dual boot on workstation Dell Precision 3500chasis.
Configuration is as follows:

Intel(R) Xeon(R)w3670 3.2GHz.  12 M cache.6C. 24 (6*4)GB ram.

After boot from CD, only Ubuntu logo showed up, after that it parses some line on screen,
The process stop at that point only.

I Boot  Opensuse 11.3 with CD, it works.

But I want to use Ubuntu instead.  Does anyone have any ideas?

I would be ever so grateful for your help.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 should run just fine in your system , check [md5sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM), of ISO image.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/40340/does-not-boot-after-installation-on-dell-precision-t3500

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should try booting with nomodeset.  You set this with the menu under F6 on the grub boot menu.

Nice instructions here in this [ubuntu forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132)

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply and suggestion...                        I tried ubuntu 11.10 after suggestion..But the same things happend ... Ubuntu sign apper on the screen ..Then folowing lines like..Write cache: enable, read cache:enable, doesn't support DPO or FUA...and a a few lines...Process stop suddenly...Please help me to get rid of these...

Answer (score -2):

As he mentioned you can use lower versions of ubuntu or try installing ubuntu from here - http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer
It's really easy to install using it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply and suggestion... I tried ubuntu 11.10 after suggestion..But the same things happend ... Ubuntu sign apper on the screen ..Then folowing lines like..Write cache: enable, read cache:enable, doesn't support DPO or FUA...and a a few lines...Process stop suddenly...Please help me to get rid of these...

Comment: Hi Friends,Thanks to all for your suggestion..as per the suggestion I tried with  NOMODESET option. With these I able to install UBUNTU 12.04 LTS, But when the system  restarted after installation, screen appeared totally blank..What to do????? Please  help me to sort out these problem...( To  use nomodeset option I press F6 and select nomodeset..afterward select install ubuntu option..)